Databricks remove DBPROPERTY
I need to remove DBPROPERTIES (let's assume property is named mydbproperty) from one of the schemas in Databricks Unity Catalog. I cannot find a proper syntax to do so.
I tried using UNSET command just like for TBLPROPERTIES, but the I got syntax error.
How can I remove the DBPROPERTY?
